# Mixing debug and non debug mode during execution - race condition?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, debugging

I have an application that connects to different databases depending on the build configuration. In #DEBUG I access the test database and in #RELEASE I access the productive system. This usually works as expected but sometimes I appear to receive test data though being on #RELEASE or the other way.

The application uses a WCF connection to connect to a Web Service that handles the database access. If the program is built with #DEBUG the WCF connection uses different authentication data to distinguish between the modes.

```
public static DBUpdaterClient CreateWebServiceInstance(ApplicationType appType)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += EasyCertCheck;

    switch (appType)
    {
        case ApplicationType.xxx:
            return new DBUpdaterClient
            {
                ClientCredentials =
                {
                    UserName =
                    {
#if DEBUG
                        UserName = "xxx_test",
                        Password = "xxx"
#else
                        UserName = "xxx",
                        Password = "xxx"
#endif
                    }
                }
            };
        ...
     }
     ...
}
```

The Web Service identifies the "test" part within the user name (or not) and establishes a database connection.

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
    switch (userName)
    {
        case "xxx":
            Helpers.CurrentUserCredentials = new WebServiceCredentials(ApplicationType.xxx, false);
        case "xxx_test":
            Helpers.CurrentUserCredentials = new WebServiceCredentials(ApplicationType.xxx, true);
                break;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Depending on the WebServiceCredential object the connection data is retrieved from Web.config via the ConfigurationManager class.

```
public DBSettings(WebServiceCredentials userCredentials)
{
    switch (userCredentials.ApplicationType)
    {
        case ApplicationType.XXX:
                XXXConnectionString = (userCredentials.IsTestMode)
                    ? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXXTest"].ConnectionString
                    : ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXXProd"].ConnectionString;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In most cases this works (let's say about 99%). But sometimes a connection to the wrong database is established and wrong data is retrieved or written (much worse).

The application itself does not use any tasks or background operations. But the application is used by about 10 users at the same time. The WCF connection is configured as `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`. I think the error must be on the client side somewhere but I have no steps to reproduce the problem. It just happens.

I am thankful for every little hint.

Comment: You could output the user messages to two text files during run the Switch case and read the database like Console.Writeline(username+Date), and then compare the two text files, so you could really find the differences and know that which user impacts the result. Since you use the test users and real users in the same app, a better suggestion is that put them in two separate projects(one project with testing data and one real project).

Comment: We examined the requests from client to server ... the client NEVER sends credentials to access the productive system in DEBUG mode. As we cannot figure out why this happens, we decided to use 2 separate web service, one to access the test databases and one to access the productive databases though it's not our preferred approach because of redundant code bases

Comment: for this issue, it is really hard for developers to find the real reason if the test data and productive data use the same service, so I agree with you, use two separate web services would be a better choice/solution.